# Getting predicted classes from R glmnet object

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

I am trying to build simple multi-class logistic regression models using glmnet in R. However when I try to predict the test data and obtain contingency table I get an error. A sample session is reproduced below.

```
> mat = matrix(1:100,nrow=10)
> test = matrix(1:50,nrow=5)

> classes <- as.factor(11:20)

> model <- glmnet(mat, classes, family="multinomial", alpha=1)
> pred <- predict(model, test)
> table(pred, as.factor(11:15))
  Error in table(pred, as.factor(11:15)) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

Any help will be appreciated. R noob here.

Thanks.

Comment: You should spend more time with the documentation. Read `?predict.glmnet` carefully, paying particular attention to the arguments `type` and `s`.

Comment: @joran :I had tried type=class, response and link also. Had not worked still :-(

Comment: Once again, you simply need to read more carefully. The `type` argument expects a character, as in `type = "class"`. Second, the `s` argument is very clearly documented, and necessary for what you are attempting. There's even an example illustrating its use.

Comment: Yes, I was using the ``type`` argument correctly, but was not supplying ``s``. Thanks for pointing it out. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! :)

Comment: @joran: `glmnet::glmnet` differs (fairly pointlessly) from `stats::glm` in at least three different ways: x must be a matrix (blows up on data.frame), type must be a string (unlike glm), and `predict.glmnet` returns an array unless you give it a specific s value. The value of s to give is not at all obvious. I was just independently migrating some glm code and hit each of these identical annoyances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `predict` method for a `glmnet` object requires that you specify a value for the argument `s`, which indicates which values of the regularization parameter for which you want predictions.

(`glmnet` fits the model for several values of this regularization parameter simultaneously.)

So if you don't specify a value for `s`, `predict.glmnet` returns predictions for *all* the values. If you want just a single set of predictions, you need to either set a value for `s` when you call `predict`, or you need to extract the relevant column after the fact.